# How can I add JSF code to xhtml in the attribute id?

Tags: jsf, facelets, uirepeat

I am working with JSF 2.2 and I would like use JSF variables in the id attribute for to send individuals petitions for each list's element.

For example:

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{bean.numbers}" var="number">
     <h:inputText id="text#{number}"/>
 </ui:repeat>
```

Thank you